# R data table: Why are values of concatenated list lost?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working through the introductory `data.table` vignette where in section *g) Why keep j so flexible?* an example is shown that's relevant to my use case:

```
DT[, .(val = list(c(a,b))), by = ID]
#    ID         val
# 1:  b 1,2,3,7,8,9
# 2:  a  4, 5,10,11
# 3:  c        6,12
```

I have a minimal working example to illustrate the problem

```
set.seed(1234)
size         <- 10
ordering_ids <- rep(1:size, sample(1:size, replace=TRUE))
products     <- letters[seq_along(ordering_ids)]
k            <- data.table(o=ordering_ids, p=products)
```

For `size <- 10`, most likely some entries result in `NA` but that's not the problem. The problem is, that beyond a certain `size` (around 6), I lose entries in the concatenated lists:

```
k
#      o  p
#  1:  1  a
#  2:  1  b
#  3:  2  c
#  4:  2  d
#  5:  2  e
#  6:  2  f
#  7:  2  g
#  8:  2  h
#  9:  2  i
# 10:  3  j
# 11:  3  k
# 12:  3  l
# 13:  3  m
# 14:  3  n
# 15:  3  o
# 16:  3  p
# 17:  4  q
# 18:  4  r
# [...]
```

Running the same command from the vignette:

```
k[o<=4, .(val=list(c(p))), by=o]
#    o          val
# 1: 1          a,b
# 2: 2 c,d,e,f,g,h,
# 3: 3 j,k,l,m,n,o,
# 4: 4 q,r,s,t,u,v,
```

Now, for orders `o=3`, the `val` list does not contain all entries (see the `k` print out, it should go until `r`).

What is the problem here and how could I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps it is just not printed. Type `k[, .(val=list(c(p))), by=o]$val[4]` to verify  the value.

Comment: I see, i did in fact think so but was printing wrongly

Comment: If you're only doing it to browse the data in a more succinct form, there's `k[, toString(p), by=o]`. I brought up the issue of the list being truncated at 6 items here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1523#issuecomment-349717900

Comment: Good hint, thanks for linking

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing this out; the default printing behavior of non-atomic columns will now include `...` as a suffix when it's truncated.

Your example (with `set.seed(1234)` will now result in the following):

```
k[o<=4, .(val=list(c(p))), by=o]
# 　　o             val
# 1: 1             a,b
# 2: 2 c,d,e,f,g,h,...
# 3: 3 j,k,l,m,n,o,...
# 4: 4 q,r,s,t,u,v,...
```